# How to extract images from Information?

Tags: machine-learning

```mathematica
class = Classify[
  ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "UCILetter"}, "Data"]]
Information@class
```

I have queried the Information function, but I can't find a solution

[image]

Comment: What image do you want to extract? Do you want to get an image of the learning curve plot? You can just export it as an image:
$$ $$
`lc = Information[class, "LearningCurve"]`
$$ $$
`Export["EXPORT_PATH.png", lc]`

Comment: @ydd There are multiple images here, so you can only export one image by doing this